# how could i append all even numbers from list1 into list2?

Tags: python

this is the code its just following questions i have  received but i have been asked to append all even numbers from list1 into list2 how could i achieve this

```
import random

list1 = []
for x in range(10):
print(random.randint(1,101))
list1.append(x)
list2 = list1

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

i have checked all over google cant find a page that can help me i have tried :

```
num = list1
if (num % 2) == 0:
  print("{0} is Even".format(num))
else:
  print("{0} is Odd".format(num))
```

Comment: interesting that you already do `list1.append(x)` but don't know how to apply this to your code with a loop

Comment: Dupes list edited;

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to append, you can create `list2` through a list comprehension:

```
list2 = [i for i in list1 if i%2==0]
# [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

If you really want to use a loop with `append`, you can do:

```
# create empty list
list2 = []
# loop through and append if even:
for i in list1:
    if i%2 == 0:
        list2.append(i)
```